# convertion from 8 bits Binary to Hexadecimal

Tags: java

when I am trying to convert 8 digit Binary to Hexa decimal
(Ex:**00001010** the output is **A**)but I need **0A** and also(Ex:**10100000** the output is **A**)but i need output as **A0**.

How to write code in java?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: could you show us how are you converting that values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `String.format` as next:

```
int value = 0b10100000;
System.out.println(String.format("%02x", value));
value = 0b00001010;
System.out.println(String.format("%02x", value));
```

**Output:**

```
a0
0a
```

If you want to have it in capital letters use `%02X` instead of `%02x` then you will get:

**Output:**

```
A0
0A
```

**Response Update:**

You get an exception because this format expect an `integer` while you provide a `String` so you need to convert it into an `integer` using `2` as radix in this case as next:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        System.out.println(String.format("%02x", Integer.parseInt(userKey[i][j], 2)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
8a
a2
ca
9a
0a
a2
ca
9a
0a
a2
ca
9a
0a
a2
ca
9a
```

Comment: public class Demo{
static int i,j;
static String userKey[][]={{"10001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"},{"00001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"},{"00001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"},{"00001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"}};
public static void main(String aargs[]){
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
for(j=0;j<4;j++){
System.out.println(String.format("02x",userKey[i][j]);
}
It gives Exception sir.

Comment: sir I did not understand why you have taken 0b before the Binary value.tell me why sir?

Comment: 0b is for binary literals, read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Comment: You get an exception because your input data is a String while my input is an integer, you need to parse first

Comment: Thanku So much sir.I got the output sir.Really Your Answer is very Helpful to my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo{
static int i,j;
static String userKey[][]={{"10001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"},{"00001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"},{"00001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"},{"00001010","10100010","11001010","10011010"}};
public static void main(String aargs[]){
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
for(j=0;j<4;j++){
System.out.println(String.format("02x",userKey[i][j]);
}
It gives Exception sir.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo
{
static int count=0;
static String res[]=new String[16];
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter text");
String abc="";
char[] messChar = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < messChar.length; i++) 
abc+= Integer.toBinaryString(messChar[i]);
System.out.println(abc.length());   
int leg=(int)((abc.length()/128)+1);
String[] spl=new String[leg];   
int j=0,i;
    for( i=0;i<abc.length();i++)
    {
        if(count==128)
        {
            if(i==128)
                spl[j]=abc.substring(0,128);
            else
            spl[j]=abc.substring(i-128,i);
            count=0;
            j++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    spl[j]=abc.substring(i-count,i);
    for(int k=0;k<spl.length;k++)
        System.out.println(spl[k].length());
    for(i=0;i<spl.length;i++)
    {
        String binary=spl[i];
        System.out.println(binary);
    }

}
```

}
Sir if we enter Any text,It will convert into Binary and then divide into 128 bits.But last There are some bits which are less than 128 bits.How to padding to those bits to get 128 bits.

Comment: Sir please give reply to my question.